# Changing a column to look like a rank (SQL or R)

Tags: sql, r, dataframe, datatable

I have a very large table, which follows these structure (I past it here simplified):

| Product | Line | Name | Quantity | Unit | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pepe | 10000 | Lucia | 4 | UD | 8 |
| Pepe | 70000 | Santiago | 7 | UD | 5.5 |
| Pepe | 70000 | Mariangeles | 10 | KG | 6 |
| Antonio | 10000 | Naiara | 4 | KG | 8 |
| Antonio | 70000 | Toni | 7 | KG | 3 |
| Vanesa | 10000 | Lucia | 4 | UD | 8 |
| Vanesa | 50000 | Santiago | 7 | KG | 8 |
| Vanesa | 50000 | Toni | 10 | KG | 3 |
| Vanesa | 50000 | Gines | 4 | KG | 8 |

I need to transform the column Line, I need the number repeated (70000, 50000...) to look like a rank (10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000...) for each Product.

| Product | Line | Name | Quantity | Unit | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pepe | 10000 | Lucia | 4 | UD | 8 |
| Pepe | 20000 | Santiago | 7 | UD | 5.5 |
| Pepe | 30000 | Mariangeles | 10 | KG | 6 |
| Antonio | 10000 | Naiara | 2 | KG | 8 |
| Antonio | 20000 | Toni | 7 | KG | 3 |
| Vanesa | 10000 | Lucia | 4 | UD | 8 |
| Vanesa | 20000 | Santiago | 7 | KG | 8 |
| Vanesa | 30000 | Toni | 10 | KG | 3 |
| Vanesa | 40000 | Gines | 4 | KG | 8 |

I can do it using SQL (DBeaver or Microsoft Access) or R, I am thinking about an R loop or a SQL complex query with count(), but some help would be very appreciated.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: In R, use dplyr: `dfr %>% group_by(Product) %>% mutate(Line = row_number() * 10000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R`, we can group by 'Product', multiply the `row_number()` by the `first` element of 'Line'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Product) %>%
    mutate(Line = row_number() * first(Line)) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 6
#  Product  Line Name        Quantity Unit   Cost
#  <chr>   <int> <chr>          <int> <chr> <dbl>
#1 Pepe    10000 Lucia              4 UD      8  
#2 Pepe    20000 Santiago           7 UD      5.5
#3 Pepe    30000 Mariangeles       10 KG      6  
#4 Antonio 10000 Naiara             4 KG      8  
#5 Antonio 20000 Toni               7 KG      3  
#6 Vanesa  10000 Lucia              4 UD      8  
#7 Vanesa  20000 Santiago           7 KG      8  
#8 Vanesa  30000 Toni              10 KG      3  
#9 Vanesa  40000 Gines              4 KG      8
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Product = c("Pepe", "Pepe", "Pepe", "Antonio", 
"Antonio", "Vanesa", "Vanesa", "Vanesa", "Vanesa"), Line = c(10000L, 
70000L, 70000L, 10000L, 70000L, 10000L, 50000L, 50000L, 50000L
), Name = c("Lucia", "Santiago", "Mariangeles", "Naiara", "Toni", 
"Lucia", "Santiago", "Toni", "Gines"), Quantity = c(4L, 7L, 10L, 
4L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 4L), Unit = c("UD", "UD", "KG", "KG", "KG", 
"UD", "KG", "KG", "KG"), Cost = c(8, 5.5, 6, 8, 3, 8, 8, 3, 8
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 1):

in sql you can use `window function`:

```
select * , 10000 * ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by product order by line) as rn
from yourtable
```

I used Line to order the rows in each group , you can chnage it to whatever make sense